# FreeNAS ports/pkg not working after update to 9.10

Tags: freebsd, truenas, freebsd-ports

I recently updated to FreeNAS 9.10 stable via the UI and now I'm having trouble with my packages and ports on my oldest existing portjail.

It seems the catalog won't update and I can't really install anything - either by `ports` or `pkg`.

My `pkg` version is quite old at `1.2.7_4` and `pkg update -f` downloads some files but then ends like this:

```
pkg: package field incomplete: comment
Incremental update completed, 24830 packages processed:
0 packages updated, 0 removed and 24830 added.
pkg: Unable to find catalogs
```

No matter what I do it keeps complaining about the catalogs. I have a newer plugin jail with `pkg` version `1.7.2` and it seems to work fine but I'd rather not migrate everything across if possible.

My `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf` file is:

```
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  enabled: yes
}
```

I then tried running `portsnap fetch update` then rebuild `ports-mgmt/portmaster` and `ports-mgmt/pkg` to bring them up to date as suggested in a few places, but running `make` gives me:

```
"/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk", line 1166: UNAME_r (10.3-RELEASE) and OSVERSION (902502) do not agree on major version number.
```

I was able to build ports such as perl 5.20 shortly after the update so something I did while trying to fix `pkg` seems to have broken this.

Answer (score 1):

My copy of `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf` read as follows in my jail:

```
FreeBSD: {                  
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:9:x86:64/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",       
  enabled: yes              
}
```

I changed that to 10 and it worked correctly

```
FreeBSD: {                  
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/freebsd:10:x86:64/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",       
  enabled: yes              
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Didn't seem to help though, still getting "pkg: Unable to find catalogs". I probably messed something else up along the way but I'm too new at this to tell :(